# How to disable a key from ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, key

My keyboard is not working properly, the dot (.) key is getting pressed automatically.
Can anyone tell me how can I disable a key from ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal type `xev -event keyboard`. Then press the button you want to disable and look for its `keycode`. On this case the keycode for `"." (period sign)` key is 60. Then run this:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 60 ='
```

If you want to re-enable it, run:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 60 = period greater period greater'
```

Comment: what was the _period greater period greater_ part of the answer?